# Posicion fixed en row (materialize)

Tags: html, css, materialize

Estoy trabajando con materialize para mi página web y Tengo la siguiente fila:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col m3">contenido pequeño</div>
 <div class="col m6">Gran contenido</div>
 <div class="col m3">contenido pequeño</div>
</div>
```

El motivo de mi pregunta es para saber, como hago que las col m3 sean estaticas y que solo la col m6 se le pueda hacer scroll, lo que deseo hacer es parecido a facebook, he intentado hacer lo siguiente:
`style="position: fixed"` pero no he obtenido resultados

Como lo puedo solucionar? de antemano les agradezco

Comment: Y colocando los m3 fuera de row?

Comment: Deberías crear un [mcve] para que viéramos el problema. Además, deberías incluir más información en la pregunta: ¿a qué te refieres con parecido a facebook? ¿Puedes añadir una imagen de cómo quieres que se vea? Puede haber usuarios que no utilicen facebook o que facebook cambie su distribución en el futuro.

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar tu problema simplemente debes jugar con las posiciones fijas y la altura del contenido al cual quieres aplicarle el scroll, algo como esto:

```css
.col{
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
}

#columna_1{
    background: chocolate;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#columna_2{
    background: gray;
    overflow: auto;
}

#columna_2 > div{
    height: 5000px;
}

#columna_3{
    background: chocolate;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">


<div class="row">
    <div class="col m3" id="columna_1">contenido pequeño</div>
    <div class="col m6 offset-m3" id="columna_2">Gran contenido
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m3" id="columna_3">contenido pequeño</div>
</div>
```